# Update OpenGL version to 4.6 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-18.04, opengl

I have problem related my nvidia driver in Ubuntu 18.04. Actually the problem occurred in computer server and I remote the computer server by using X2Go.

My Computer Server using Ubuntu 18.04
And using NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1080 TI

I am using the method to install Nvidia Drivers from this:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

And actually it installed the latest driver as I am check using **nvidia-smi**: wheras showing I am using driver 440.26 which means the latest driver.

But when I check my openGL using **glxinfo | grep ':'** it showing that my openGL version is **3.1** which is not latest update. 
I really need to **upgrade my openGL version to 4.6**.

I am struggle for hours to do this but I can't. Could someone tell me how to proceed please?

Thank you to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly WHICH version string are you referring to?

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Mon Nov  4 16:39:17 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.50       Driver Version: 430.50       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P8    15W / 160W |    887MiB /  5931MiB |      5%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1491      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           367MiB |
|    0      4325      G   compiz                                       358MiB |
|    0     22829      G   freecad-daily                                  3MiB |
|    0     22858      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       4MiB |
|    0     22893      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                     151MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$ glxinfo | grep -i version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 430.50
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.50
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 430.50
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
```

---

Check which glx/mesa you have (I'm running 16.04/Xenial still):

```
$ dpkg --list | grep -i "glx"
ii  libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64                                       18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1                      amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX development files
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                                       18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1                      amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libxcb-glx0:amd64                                           1.11.1-1ubuntu1                              amd64        X C Binding, glx extension
ii  libxcb-glx0-dev:amd64                                       1.11.1-1ubuntu1                              amd64        X C Binding, glx extension, development files
```

Comment: This string, mine is:

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.3.0-devel (git-ff6e148 2019-10-29 bionic-oibaf-ppa)

I want to update into 4.6.0 or at least 4.3.0